# Asset Browser only displays the file names and not the preview icons

Tags: asset-browser, asset

[image]

I use Blender 4.0 and the Asset Browser only displays the file names and not the preview icons. Other forums says you can change the preview through the *View*, but there's nothing in there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

[image]